# Codeigniter - REST_SERVER e Datatables (plugin)

Tags: codeigniter, rest, jquery-datatables

Estou com um problema ao utilizar ao biblioteca [REST_SERVER](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)  e o plugin [datatables](https://datatables.net/).

O controller está ok, o problema está na autenticação Ajax, pois se eu utilizar a primeira requisição `Ajax`, conforme abaixo, eu consigo exibir os dados perfeitamente e trabalhar com a tabela.

Mas se eu utilizar o ultimo código `ajax`, conforme documentação `Datatables`, eu não consigo trabalhar como no primeiro código `ajax`.

Por exemplo, ao executar
`$('#table').ajax.reload(null, false);` a session é destruída, como se a `autenticação header` não estivesse funcionando.

**Vejam meu controlador**

```
class Api_account extends REST_Controller...
public function getAll_accounts_get()
{
    $draw = intval($this->input->get('draw'));
    $start = intval($this->input->get('start'));
    $length = intval($this->input->get('length'));

    $query = $this->db->get('tb_account');

    $data = [];
    foreach ($query->result() as $r)
    {
        $line = [];
        $type = $r->type;
        $description = [
            1 => 'Conta Corrente',
            2 => 'Poupança',
            3 => 'Outros'
        ];

        $r->default == 1 ? $default = 'Default' : $default = 'No';
        $r->default == 1 ? $class = 'positive' : $class = 'negative';

        $line[] = $r->description;
        $line[] = $description[$type] ? : 'undefined type';
        $line[] = 'R$ '.number_format($r->balance, 2,',','.');
        $line[] = '<div class="'.$class.' rounded-20 inline-block"></div><span>'.' '.ucfirst($default).'</span>';

        $read   = '<button id="'.$r->id.'" class="btn-read">read</button>';
        $update = '<button id="'.$r->id.'" class="btn-update">update</button>';
        $delete = '<button id="'.$r->id.'" class="btn-delete">delete</button>';

        $line[] = [$read.' '.$update.' '.$delete];

        $data[] = $line;
    }

    $result = [
        'draw'            => $draw,
        'recordsTotal'    => $query->num_rows(),
        'recordsFiltered' => $query->num_rows(),
        'data'            => $data
    ];

    $this->response($result, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

**Ajax funcional**

```js
function getAllAccontsAjax() {
 if (responseToken != null && responseToken != '') {
  let id = jwt_decode(responseToken).id;
  let settings = {
   async: true,
   crossDomain: true,
   url: baseUrl + ci_controller + '/getAll_accounts',
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
    'authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==',
    'Authorizationkeyfortoken': String(responseToken),
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'postman-token': '51901e9b-3613-248b-621e-ffd06d92ded4'
   },
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   statusCode: {
    401: function (error) {
     console.log(error);
     location.href = base_url + 'token/logout';
    }
   }
  };
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   $('#table').dataTable({
    'scrollY': 390,
    'deferRender': true,
    'scroller': true,
    'scrollCollapse': true,
    'responsive': true,
    'dom': "frtiS",
    'bDestroy': true,
    'data': response.data,
    'columns': [
                                        {'data': 1},
     {'data': 2},
     {'data': 3},
     {'data': 4},
     {'data': 5},
    ]
   })
   $('.tooltip').tooltip('hide');
  });

  $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
   dom: 'Bfrtip'
  });
 }
}
```

**Vejam meu ajax (que não funciona)**

```js
/** Ajax **/
function initDatatable() {
 table = $('#table').DataTable({
  'scrollY': '350px',
  'scrollCollapse': true,
  'processing': false,
  'responsive': true,
  'serverSide': true,
  'dom': "frtiS",
  'deferRender': true,
  'ajax': {
   'url': baseUrl + ci_controller + '/getAll_accounts',
   'type': 'GET',
   'headers': {
    'authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==',
    'Authorizationkeyfortoken': String(responseToken),
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'postman-token': '51901e9b-3613-248b-621e-ffd06d92ded4'
   },
  },
 });
 debugger;

 $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  dom: 'Bfrtip'
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei por qual motivo isso acontece, mas o problema está na configuração da sessão.

Resolvi o problema, alterando a seguinte linha do arquivo `config.php`

**ANTES**
`$config['sess_expiration'] = -1;`

**AGORA**
`$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;`

Na primeira configuração, eu estava deixando como `-1`, pois evitaria que a sessão expirasse, mas como passei por este problema, tive que alterar para `7200`